# GraphQL - How to search multiple fields?

Tags: graphql

I'm very new to GraphQL, and struggling with searching. I need to do a keyword search that could appear in any of the **address** fields or the **name** of either the **location** or **topLevelItem**. (So an OR relationship between individual fields). How would I alter the query to do that? All the examples I can find are only for searching a single field.

```
query {
  topLevelItems {
    elements {
      id
      name
      location {
        id
        name
        address {
          houseNumber
          houseNumberAddition
          street
          city
          postalCode
          countryCode
          phone
        }
      }
    }
    pageInfo {
      numberOfElements
      totalElements
      totalPages
      hasPrevious
      hasNext
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Based on the query you provided, it does not receive any argument. Your query should receive an argument `keyword` of type string and your GraphQL resolver should do the search. The search process is not GraphQL's job for your information.

Comment: graphql can only pass your conditions object (any complexity) as parameter - if/how/what syntax is a resolver/server resonsibility, can be supported or not (check API specs) - write your own